# Writing a system call to return pid of process

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm writing a syscall that return the pid of a process when you provide its name. It returns the pid once it finds the value or -1 when it doesn't.

I follow all the steps to write a system call:
Adding the syscall in syscall table, adding it in syscalls.h, changed linux/Makefile, created a directory called pname. Compiling was smooth, everything finished. This is my pname.c

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include "pname.h"
asmlinkage int pnametoid(char* name){

 struct task_struct *task;

 struct tty_struct *my_tty;

 my_tty = get_current_tty();

 for_each_process(task){

 if(strcmp(task->comm, name) == 0)
    return task->pid;
 }
 return -1;
}
```

This is my test program test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
 char name[32];
 puts("Enter process to find");
 scanf("%s",name);
 strtok(name, "\n");
 int status = syscall(317, name); //syscall number 317 and passing in the 
string. 
printf("System call returned %d\n", status);
return 0;
}
```

I try entering process names like "test" or "sshd" but the return value is always -1 instead of the pid. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried printing name before using it in strtok and syscall function? To see if you're getting the string that you expect when you typed

Comment: @josemartindev hey i tried what you said and yeah the string is what i typed

Comment: Try to `printk()` both `task->comm` and `name` inside `for_each_process` to ensure that you compare exactly what you want to compare. Then check the output of this in `dmesg`.

Comment: I suspect that `char* name` inside `pnametoid` does not point to the string you pass into the syscall in recent kernels, if you insert `pnametoid` directly to the syscalls table. The reason for this suspicion is that in recent kernels an additional wrapper around syscall functions is used, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027649/memory-isolation-in-new-linux-kernels-or-what/55174798#55174798 - probably your `char *name` actually contains a pointer to `struct pt_regs` instead of a pointer to the string passed by the calling process.

Comment: you may like to see getpid() system call implementation. See here:  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sys.c#L891