# Syscall hijacking: How to pass arguments?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to register a new syscall hacking the syscall table. I'm able to register a function as syscall and I can properly call it. However, I'm not able to pass arguments.

I'm working on Linux ubuntu, kernel version 5.0.0-25.

copy_from_user and copy_to_user do not return any error but simply the data are not copied. Also passing just a  value doesn't work since I read random value from the kernel side.

Currently, my implementation looks like:

```
unsigned long sys_call_table = 0xffffffffbb6001e0;
unsigned long sys_ni_syscall = 0xffffffffba6bd800;

asmlinkage int sys_my_first_sys_call(void){
    printk("%s: zero-params sys-call has been called\n",MODNAME);
    return 0;
}

asmlinkage int sys_my_second_sys_call(int a){
    printk("%s: 1-param sys-call has been called (with param %d)\n",MODNAME,a);
    return 0;
}

unsigned long new_sys_call_array[HACKED_ENTRIES] = {sys_my_first_sys_call,sys_my_second_sys_call};

int init_module(void) {

    unsigned long * p = (unsigned long *) sys_call_table;
    int i,j;
    int ret;

    unsigned long cr0;

    printk("%s: initializing\n",MODNAME);
    j = -1;
    for (i=0; i<256; i++){
        if (p[i] == sys_ni_syscall){
            printk("%s: table entry %d keeps address %p\n",MODNAME,i,(void*)p[i]);
            j++;
            restore[j] = i;
            if (j == (HACKED_ENTRIES-1)) break;
        }
    }

    cr0 = read_cr0();
        write_cr0(cr0 & ~X86_CR0_WP);
    for(i=0;i<HACKED_ENTRIES;i++){
        p[restore[i]] = (unsigned long)new_sys_call_array[i];
    }
    write_cr0(cr0);

    printk("%s: all new system-calls correctly installed on sys-call table \n",MODNAME);

    ret = 0;

    return ret;
}
```

Userspace, I call the sycall in the following way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    int sys_call_num, arg;

    if(argc < 2){ 
                printf("usage: prog syscall-num [syscall-param]\n");
                return;
        }


        sys_call_num = strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);
        if (argv[2]){
            arg = strtol(argv[2],NULL,10);
            syscall(sys_call_num,arg);
            return 0;
        }

    syscall(sys_call_num);

    return 0;
}
```

Calling the syscall and passing it a params results in printing random values like

`1-param sys-call has been called (with param -1017053352)`

anyone has any idea why this happens? I don't think it is a bug...

Comment: How are you making your syscall from userspace?

Comment: You should add the relevant code where you actually make the syscall.

Comment: yes, done. Sorry!

Comment: @EmanueleVannacci on which syscall numbers are you installing your custom syscalls?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Actually, I iterate over the syscall table looking for an entry pointing to sys_ni_syscall and I put my syscalls there. When I mount the module, I usually put the syscalls at 134 and 174

Comment: @EmanueleVannacci well, syscall 174 is `create_module`, which is not implemented and therefore takes no arguments. I don't know much about how syscall resolution works in the kernel but that seems like it could be a problem: the kernel thinks syscall 174 needs no arguments and doesn't bother passing the correct value. Could that be the case?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I tried putting the syscall at 180. it is supposed to be sys_nfsservctl, actually not implemented and accepting 3 args. The result does not change... Btw I don't think that  putting a function accepting more args than the functions supposed to be at that location should matter...

Comment: Moreover, I'm pretty sure that on previous kernel versions the code is gonna work because I remember trying this in the past successfully. However, I cannot check it...

Comment: @EmanueleVannacci could it be that your syscall is not going to have any parameter passed by the kernel because it's supposed to be unimplemented? Maybe you should try replacing an existing syscall (even though I would not suggest playing around with that outside of a VM). You can write a simple wrapper for something like `exit` for example, that executes your code and then calls the real `exit`.

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027649/memory-isolation-in-new-linux-kernels-or-what/55174798#55174798) - most probably the random values you see in the arguments are the pointers to `struct pt_regs` instances. In short - in most recent kernels functions which reside directly in the syscalls table receive not the arguments themselves, but a pointer to the structure with these arguments, so you see not the argument, but a pointer. Allocation algorithm places the structure _somewhere_, and, thus, the pointer is pretty "random", of course.

Comment: @DanilaKiver @MarcoBonelli yes, that was the issue! I modified the syscall in order to accept only the arg `const struct pt_regs *regs` and passing a value I can find it in the  `di` field of the struct!

Comment: @EmanueleVannacci OK, then I will flag current question as a duplicate too. Glad that this stuff helped.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to register a new syscall hacking the syscall table.

This is not a supported method of adding system calls. It will not work reliably or correctly.

If you want to add a system call, add it in the kernel itself, and rebuild the kernel. See the kernel documentation on "[Adding a New System Call](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.2/process/adding-syscalls.html)" for details, but focus in particular on the section describing "System Call Alternatives" -- there are many ways to add functionality to the kernel without adding a new system call.

Comment: This question is about syscall hijacking though, of course it is not the right way to add a system call. The objective is to replace an existing syscall with an arbitrary function, therefore *hijacking* it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Right. My concern is that system call hijacking is explicitly an unsupported technique, and that the OP may have been misled into thinking that this is an appropriate thing for a kernel module to do.

Comment: @duskwuff Thank you for your answer! However I know that this is an unsupported technique, but I cannot rebuild the kernel. I just need an easy way to run kernel code and pass it parameters.

Comment: If that was the case, OP wouldn't have talked about "hijacking" and wouldn't have used names like `HACKED_ENTRIES`.

Comment: @EmanueleVannacci You don't need to create a new system call to run code in the kernel. Read the section of the documentation titled "System Call Alternatives".

Answer (score 0):

sys_ni_syscall is an invalid system call.
It is defined as no params passed in, so you can't pass params into this syscall [sys_ni_syscall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuKsL.png)

It is called when an invalid system call number is passed in.